# Will Shaitan receive the worst punishment in Jahannam?

Tags: shaitan, punishment, jahannam

The hypocrites and shirk committers will receive the worst punishments in hell. Will shaitan recieve a worse punishment than them?

Answer (score 1):

From Surah Al-Maeda Verse No:60:

> Say, "Should I tell you who will receive the worst punishment from
>   God? Those whom God has condemned, afflicted with His anger, made apes
>   out of them, swine and worshippers of Satan, will have the worst
>   dwelling and will wander far away from the right path."

this and The matter of punishments is for Allaah to decide, and we know nothing about it except that which He has told us.